# CDLIB : NMI (Normalized Mutual Information) function is not working can anyone help here?

Tags: python

I'm trying to evaluate the result of an algorithm of community detection. (Comparison between detected communities and truth community).
I used DBLP dataset but the function can't work it gives me this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\w\Dropbox\thesis_motaz_ben_hassine\implementations\h_clustering_new_Sim.py", line 323, in <module>
    nmi=evaluation.normalized_mutual_information(res_omega_nmi,communities_omega_nmi)
  File "c:\users\w\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\cdlib\evaluation\comparison.py", line 69, in normalized_mutual_information
    __check_partition_coverage(first_partition, second_partition)
  File "c:\users\w\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\cdlib\evaluation\comparison.py", line 36, in __check_partition_coverage
    raise ValueError("Both partitions should cover the same node set")
ValueError: Both partitions should cover the same node set
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use NMI between two community algorithms with the same graph.